# Command-T for MacVim

Tags: vim

I have installed Macvim and Akita. Commant-T doesn't work, and it returns the following error:

> E73: tag stack empty

How do I configure it?

Comment: Are you talking about the Command-T plugin? What happens when you type `:CommandT`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error appears because you are typing `<C-t>` (Ctrl+t) instead of `<leader>t`, Command-t's default mapping.

`<C-t>` is used to come back to the usage of a tag after jumping to its definition.

This error may happen if you don't have an up to date `tags` file or if your cursor is on something that is not a tag or if you didn't jump to a definition previously.